# Images not showing up on server but working fine on localhost in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, digital-ocean

I'm working on a node js app and I have some images which I want to show on the frontend but after publishing the app on the digital-ocean server images are not showing up

Below is how the image directory structured

```
|__ static
  |__ assets
    |__ favicon
    |__ images
```

Index.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

HTML files (Using EJS)

```
<img src="/assets/images/banner.png">
```

Images are working fine on localhost but not on the server. Can't figure out the reason for this, Any leads would be great.

Update:

I checked for folder permission and it seems fine.
Found a work around but not sure about the reason for this issue, I removed the parent directory assets and moved the child directory directly under static and after this it worked perfectly fine.

Any explanation on this issue might help to understand.

Comment: try this: **app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));**

Comment: No this didn’t worked

Comment: Found a working solution but still not sure about the reason. I removed the parent directory assets and moved other directories like images, favicon directly under static and it worked after that!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the folder permission ? That might be blocking you from publicly accessing files within the folder. You want to have 755 permission.

Comment: Permission is seems correct. Found a working solution but still not sure about the reason. I removed the parent directory assets and moved other directories like images, favicon directly under static and it worked after that!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and it was because I had a `nginx` configuration causing issues. When I looked in the server logs, I saw the server trying to serve files located `/usr/share/nginx/html/` instead of where they were actually located. After I deleted it, the issue went away.

File: `static.conf`

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
  expires 7d;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```